# Alternatives to Yahoo Messenger for Windows

Tags: windows, software-rec, instant-messaging, yahoo-messenger

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best alternative to Windows Live Messenger](https://superuser.com/questions/80465/best-alternative-to-windows-live-messenger)

I'm looking for alternative programs other then the offical client to use with Yahoo messenger on Windows.

What options are there?  Preferably free and with no ads/spyware.

Comment: The question should be tagged with _windows_.

Comment: @kiamlaluno - Added.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try [Digsby](http://Digsby.com).  Direct download here: http://update.digsby.com/install/digsby_setup.exe

Or [Trillian](http://www.trillian.im/), though there is the option of a paid version of this one.

Answer (score 3):

I know that @Force Flow already mentioned Trillian, but I'm going to expand on this...

[Trillian](http://www.trillian.im/) is the best all-in-one solution I have ever seen.  It handles Yahoo Messenger and your contacts, etc *extremely* well.

From Wikipedia:

> It can connect to multiple IM services, such as AIM, ICQ, Windows Live Messenger, Yahoo! Messenger, IRC, Novell GroupWise Messenger, Bonjour, XMPP, and Skype networks; as well as Social Networks, such as Facebook, Twitter and MySpace; and email services, such as POP3, IMAP, Gmail, Hotmail and Yahoo! Mail.

I have used Trillian myself (the free version), which works extremely well, and does what I need it to do...

If you decide to accept Trillian as your accepted answer, **give the checkmark to @Force Flow, since he mentioned it first.**

Comment: make-or-break question here, is it skinnable?

Comment: @MifftheFox: in a word, **YES!**

Comment: Thank you for this information.  I've accepted Force Flow's answer as you specified.

Comment: @MifftheFox: thanks! hope it works well for ya! :)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you have a look at Pidgin. It's an open source messaging client which support a wide range of protocols. (Open Source programs are usually free for ads and malware, and this applies to Pidgin as well)

- [Pidgin](http://pidgin.im/)

For a more comprehensive list of the alternatives out there, check out this article on Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_instant_messaging_clients

Comment: I've had bad experiences with Pidgin's installer, but I'll take a look at aMSN.  Open source is always a plus with me.

Comment: Pidgin's installer occasionally fritzes out, but a restart usually works. Once you have it installed, it works great.

Comment: Looking at aMSN's home page, it doesn't seem to support Yahoo accounts, only MSN.

Answer (score 1):

[Pidgin](http://pidgin.im/) - multi-platform, multi-protocol. Works flawlessly under Windows/Linux.